# PostgreSQL 9.3 - Performance Issue: Counting table entries slower with jdbc postgres driver

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.3, jdbc, query-performance

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3 and want to ask if it is possible to improve the performance of my queries based on the following database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "entities" (
  "id" BIGSERIAL,
  "type" INT NOT NULL,
  "name" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  "sentence_id" BIGINT NOT NULL, -- REFERENCES sentences(sentence_id)
  "date" DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "relationships" (
  "id" BIGSERIAL,
  "type" INT NOT NULL,
  "entity1" BIGINT NOT NULL, -- REFERENCES entities(id)
  "entity2" BIGINT NOT NULL, -- REFERENCES entities(id)
  "sentence_id" BIGINT NOT NULL, -- REFERENCES sentences(sentence_id)
  "date" DATE NOT NULL
);
```

The primary key for entities is (id, name, sentence_id) and I do have index on the fields "id" and "date". The primary key for relationships is (id, entity1, entity2, sentence_id) and I also have index on "id" and "date".

I will briefly explain the domain below. Maybe some of you do know another better approach.

There are sentences containing Persons on a certain date:

```
sent_id, date, sentence
1, 27.09.1990, "Franz Beckenbauer bedankt sich bei Angela Merkel"
2, 27.09.1990, "Angela Merkel feiert ihren Abschluss in Physik"
```

From this sources I extract the following table entries for the table "entities":

```
entitie_id, name, sent_id, date
1, Angela Merkel, 1, 27-09-1990
1, Angela Merkel, 2, 27-09-1990
2, Franz Beckenbauer, 1, 27-09-1990
```

I use this query to get the frequency of entities within a given time period:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entities AS e 
WHERE e.id = {id} AND (e.date BETWEEN {from} AND {to})
```

and this one for the frequency of the relationship between them (how often they occurred together):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM relationships AS r
WHERE r.id = {id} AND (r.date BETWEEN {from} AND {to})
```

Following a working example with explain analyze:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT COUNT(*) from entities as e 
WHERE e.id = 474118 AND 
(e.date BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-12-01');

Aggregate  (cost=741.92..741.93 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.077..0.077   rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on entity e  (cost=6.66..741.46 rows=183 width=0) (actual   time=0.067..0.072 rows=4 loops=1)
     Recheck Cond: (id = 474118)
     Filter: (("date" >= '2010-01-01'::date) AND ("date" <= '2010-  12-01'::date))
     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on e_pkey_index  (cost=0.00..6.61 rows=190 width=0) (actual time=0.053..0.053 rows=4 loops=1)
           Index Cond: (id = 474118)
 Total runtime: 0.119 ms
(7 rows)
```

Is there a possibility to speed up this query or can I change the structure according to my domain to improve performance? I'm using this sort of query in my application very extensively to sort entities and relationships based on their individual frequency. In total I have run times of about more or less 6 seconds. If I can decrease a single query time this may also improve.

### EDIT:

Explain Analyze after combined index (id, date) with another id:

```
Aggregate  (cost=707.84..707.85 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.108..0.108 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on entities e  (cost=6.74..707.39 rows=181 width=0)    (actual time=0.081..0.104 rows=4 loops=1)
     Recheck Cond: ((id = 957604) AND (date >= '2010-01-01'::date) AND (date   <= '2010-12-01'::date))
     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on e_id_date_index  (cost=0.00..6.70 rows=181   width=0) (actual time=0.073..0.073 rows=4 loops=1)
           Index Cond: ((id = 957604) AND (date >= '2010-01-01'::date) AND (date <= '2010-12-01'::date))
 Total runtime: 0.168 ms
(6 rows)
```

### EDIT 2

Found the culprit. It seems that some of the queries (here the entity query) takes more than a second. This would explain why my application function, which calls relation and entity query n times, takes more than 6 seconds. Found this with the "auto_explain" module of PostgreSQL. It logs all queries from my application which takes more than a seconds automatically and performs explain analyze on them.

```
2014-08-04 00:02:25 CEST LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT COUNT(*)            FROM entities AS e           WHERE e.id = $1           AND           (e.date   BETWEEN $2 AN$
2014-08-04 00:02:25 CEST DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '879', $2 = '2010-02-09', $3 = '2010-11-24'
2014-08-04 00:02:26 CEST LOG:  duration: 1266.621 ms
2014-08-04 00:02:26 CEST LOG:  duration: 1266.547 ms  plan:
        Query Text: SELECT COUNT(*)            FROM entities AS e           WHERE e.id = $1           AND           (e.date BETWEEN $2 AND $3)
        Aggregate  (cost=85495.58..85495.59 rows=1 width=0) (actual rows=1 loops=1)
           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on entities e  (cost=4704.17..84977.27   rows=207326 width=0) (actual rows=219714 loops=1)
            Recheck Cond: (id = 879::bigint)
                Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 6437814
            Filter: ((date >= '2010-02-09'::date) AND (date <= '2010-11-  24'::date))
                 Rows Removed by Filter: 44104
                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on e_pkey_index  (cost=0.00..4652.34   rows=251720 width=0) (actual rows=263818 loops=1)
                      Index Cond: (id = 879::bigint)
```

Sorry that it is another id but it's hard to get the same twice. It seems that the problem are id's that have many entries in the entities table. After recreating the index it looks like:

```
2014-08-04 22:38:23 CEST LOG:  duration: 697.026 ms
2014-08-04 22:38:23 CEST LOG:  duration: 697.002 ms  plan:
    Query Text: SELECT COUNT(*)            FROM entities AS e           WHERE     e.id = $1           AND           (e.date BETWEEN $2 AND $3)
        Aggregate  (cost=83520.53..83520.54 rows=1 width=0) (actual rows=1   loops=1)
           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on entities e  (cost=1775.72..83319.78   rows=80297 width=0) (actual rows=81936 loops=1)
                Recheck Cond: (id = 514::bigint)
                 Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 3651177
                 Filter: ((date >= '2010-02-02'::date) AND (date <= '2010-11-  25'::date))
                Rows Removed by Filter: 11888
                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on e_pkey_index  (cost=0.00..1755.64  rows=94828 width=0) (actual rows=93824 loops=1)
                  Index Cond: (id = 514::bigint)
```

Comment: I thought about this more precise and to have a run time of 6 seconds in my application their needs to be more than 50.420 calls of this query approximately. I think this is unrealistic. The problem is maybe, that I open for each call a new database driver connection to the PostgreSQL database. This may the real culprit. I will look into it and tell you.

Comment: Try a combined index on `(id, date)`. Opening and closing the connection for each query definitely is a bad idea. You might want to consider a connection pool for this. Btw `date` (or `timestamp`) is a horrible name for a column. For one because it's also a reserved word,but more importantly because it doesn't document what it contains. A due date? A start date? An end date? A modified date? something different?

Comment: `Total runtime: 0.119 ms` .. seems quite fast to me already. Sounds like your connection idea might be the right track to follow first.

Comment: I'm using the with DB.connection [1]. I also have a connection pool with two partitions and 40 connections for each one. Found the culprit in some cases the plan prefers to filter by date instead of choosing the id by index. But I don't know how to fix it. I edit the original question according to my funds.

Comment: Your `CREATE TABLE` statement does not match the column names and data displayed. Please edit your question to make sense.

Comment: Sry, you're right. Just added the relationship table with its primary key and renamed timestamp to date in one of the explain analyze snippets. To clarify this:  Its actually two queries in the method which is called from my application and for some relationships the query takes too long. In "edit 2" the second query takes more than a second. I'm not skilled in ready the explain analyze statement, but it seems that it performs a second index scan after filtering the date. Is that right? What is wrong with this query.

Comment: Your question is still a mess. You write about (very odd) primary keys, but they do not show in the table definition (which would be much clearer. Your db design can certainly improved. Then you focus on a performance question, but compare two *different* queries on *different* tables ...

Answer (score 1):

There are too many different topics in one question, and even after many updates not all is clear. I'll just pick the **elephant in th room** and ignore the rest:

Query 1

```
->  Index Scan using r_pkey_index on relationships r (cost=0.43..57.53 rows=13 width=0)
                                                     (actual rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (id = 947367::bigint)
         Filter: ((date >= '2010-02-09'::date) AND (date <= '2010-11-24'::date))
```

Query 2

```
Filter: ((date >= '2010-02-09'::date) AND (date <= '2010-11-24'::date))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 44104
      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on e_pkey_index (cost=0.00..4652.34 rows=251720 width=0)
                                            (actual rows=263818 loops=1)
          Index Cond: (id = 879::bigint)
```

Obviously, a single row matches your criteria in the first query, while there are more than 200.000 in the second. Obviously, the first can be *much faster*.
Leaving aside that we are comparing two queries on *two different tables*.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I recreated the index for id's on the entities table and put the result in the original post. Here [1] is also a excerpt of the logs. Some queries on the entities table take longer than other. I've copied some of them into the pastebin. But interesting is that always the same id is slow and it don't uses caching. I also tried the same query with the same id (514) on a MySql database  with the same index and it only takes 100ms. [1] pastebin.com/HeQ0c8Ck

Comment: @user2715478: I have said my piece. Remember: present a clearly defined, conclusive question with the necessary context and you will get better response. For now, also consider [@a_horse's advice](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73057/postgresql-9-3-performance-issue-counting-table-entries-slower-with-jdbc-post#comment131442_73057)

Comment: Can you explain me how to read these explain analyze statements? Considering the last one in my question: Are we starting with 80297 rows and removing 3651177 nodes using the index on id? Which makes no sense and I also wonder about the last Bitmap index scan. If we already removed 3651177 rows by index why should we check a second time the index? You're right that my original question is quite confusing and you already told. But at the time I ask the question I wasn't really aware of the _real_ problem. Only after these hints I found the "problem" and I'm really thankful for your help!

Comment: @user2715478: I suggest you start a new question, since it's not the same question any more anyway.